# How to access multi-index values in Pandas for calculations

Tags: pandas

I am trying to calculate the distribution of values in a `pandas` pivot table. I am having trouble calculating the values and understanding the proper way to access multi-index series/columns.

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
person = ['Jack', 'John', 'Mark']
randoms = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['id', 'person','state', 'choice', 'num'])

for i in range(0,500):
    row = [i, random.choice(person), random.choice(randoms), random.choice(randoms), random.randrange(1, 250)]
    append_df = pd.DataFrame([row], columns=['id', 'person','state', 'choice', 'num'])
    df = df.append(append_df)

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

pd.pivot_table(
    data = df,
    index = ['person','choice'],
    columns = ['state'],
    values='num',
    aggfunc = ['sum', 'count'],
    margins=True,
    margins_name='total',
    fill_value=0
)
```

The output of the pivot table looks something like this:

```
        sum sum sum sum count   count   count   count
state       A   B   C   total   A   B   C   total
person  choice                              
Jack    A   1519    1667    1460    4646    15  13  11  39
Jack    B   2078    1641    3200    6919    17  12  28  57
Jack    C   2166    1845    3575    7586    13  17  28  58
John    A   3241    2028    1880    7149    26  20  18  64
John    B   2467    2517    1200    6184    21  23  12  56
John    C   1585    2481    2791    6857    16  19  23  58
Mark    A   2320    2647    1858    6825    20  19  18  57
Mark    B   2807    2809    3116    8732    21  24  23  68
Mark    C   1953    1503    2558    6014    11  13  19  43
total       20136   19138   21638   60912   160 160 180 500
```

What I am trying to calculate is the % of the num value by column/index to get the distribution, like so [The calc would be sum A / sum total, sum B / sum total, etc]:

```
        sum sum sum sum count   count   count   count               
state       A   B   C   total   A   B   C   total   A_Pct   B_Pct   C_Pct   total_pct
person  choice                                              
Jack    A   1519    1667    1460    4646    15  13  11  39  0.33    0.36    0.31    1.00
Jack    B   2078    1641    3200    6919    17  12  28  57  0.30    0.24    0.46    1.00
Jack    C   2166    1845    3575    7586    13  17  28  58  0.29    0.24    0.47    1.00
John    A   3241    2028    1880    7149    26  20  18  64  0.45    0.28    0.26    1.00
John    B   2467    2517    1200    6184    21  23  12  56  0.40    0.41    0.19    1.00
John    C   1585    2481    2791    6857    16  19  23  58  0.23    0.36    0.41    1.00
Mark    A   2320    2647    1858    6825    20  19  18  57  0.34    0.39    0.27    1.00
Mark    B   2807    2809    3116    8732    21  24  23  68  0.32    0.32    0.36    1.00
Mark    C   1953    1503    2558    6014    11  13  19  43  0.32    0.25    0.43    1.00
total       20136   19138   21638   60912   160 160 180 500 0.33    0.31    0.36    1.00
```

What's the best way to access the multi-index to calculate this? Is there a standard way to call indexes by name rather than levels?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# piv = pd.pivot_table(...
pct = piv['sum'].iloc[:, :-1].div(piv['sum'].iloc[:, -1], axis=0)
piv = piv.join(pd.concat([pct, pct.sum(1).rename('total')], 
                         keys=['pct', 'pct'], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
>>> piv
                 sum                      count                       pct                          
state              A      B      C  total     A    B    C total         A         B         C total
person choice                                                                                      
Jack   A        2084   1836   2453   6373    19   16   20    55  0.327005  0.288090  0.384905   1.0
       B        2875   1491   1925   6291    24   12   18    54  0.457002  0.237005  0.305993   1.0
       C        2208   3513   2084   7805    19   28   18    65  0.282896  0.450096  0.267008   1.0
John   A        2383   2755   1554   6692    19   21   11    51  0.356097  0.411686  0.232218   1.0
       B        1779   1828   2790   6397    18   16   19    53  0.278099  0.285759  0.436142   1.0
       C        1706   1841   3311   6858    12   16   24    52  0.248761  0.268446  0.482794   1.0
Mark   A        1633   2173   1117   4923    20   18   14    52  0.331708  0.441398  0.226894   1.0
       B        2099   2533   2253   6885    18   23   21    62  0.304866  0.367901  0.327233   1.0
       C        2445   1925   2652   7022    20   14   22    56  0.348191  0.274138  0.377670   1.0
total          19212  19895  20139  59246   169  164  167   500  0.324275  0.335803  0.339922   1.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the only way to truly access the multi-index by index location/integer and not name?

Comment: What do you mean? You can also use: `piv.loc[:, ('sum', ['A', 'B', 'C'])].div(piv.loc[:, ('sum', 'total')], axis=0)`